# Printed map has different scales for raster and vector layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale, basemap

I am trying to help a friend in another part of the country diagnose this problem.  She has a background layer from google and has a vector layer overlaid on it.  It looks fine in the composer but when printed the layers are scaled differently and don’t match.

QGIS version2.8.2 but she is going to upgrade to 3.2 now that is officially stable.

As can be seen from the screen shots the project CRS is 3857 and OTF enabled which should take care of the vector layer which is probably 2193.

Composer window

[image: composer window]

QGIS main window

[image: Main QGIS window]

Printed result

[image: Printed result]

Comment: Are they using the OpenLayers plugin? Possible duplicate https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=openlayers+plugin+align

Comment: Agreed there are a lot of people who have similar/related problems.  We have worked through that list and  tried suggestions that seem relevant to no avail.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen a bunch of times due to the same user error (I've made this mistake a few times as well).

I think the problem is that your friend loaded their Shapefile first in another projection then added the base map from Google (using either the OpenLayers Plugin or using the "Add XYZ Layer" option in QGIS). I would ask them what their projection reads in the bottom-right corner. If it isn't EPSG:3857, they should try changing it to that and try to output their map again. Web base maps don't scale well when they aren't printed in their standard projection.